# What is the difference between an Angular or React frontend with an API backend and a frontend with a headless CMS?

Tags: api, frontend, backend, headless-cms

I don't understand the difference between creating an application with Angular or React (or something else) on the frontend and communicating with an API for the back (and call it a CMS), and a Headless CMS.  They sound the same.  What is the difference?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

An API is a way for software to communicate with other software.

A headless CMS is a content management system that comes with an API for clients to retrieve data and **doesn't** come with its own end-user frontend (they generally come with admin frontends).